Почему в Ubuntu ffmpeg записывает черный экран и курсор мышки, и больше ничего?
Почему в ubuntu
команда ffmpeg -s 1366x768 -f x11grab -r 30 -i $DISPLAY hello.mp4 записывает черный экран и курсор мышки, и больше ничего?
здесь тоже самое ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 800x600 -r 25 -i :0.0 -vcodec qtrle screencast.mov

¿может у вас wayland?
